# Axios can't set data

Tags: vue.js, axios

Here's my data:

```
data: function(){
    return {
        contas: [{id: 3,
            nome: "Conta de telefone",
            pago: false,
            valor: 55.99,
            vencimento: "22/08/2016"}] //debug test value
    };
},
```

And here's my get request:

```
beforeMount() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1/api/bills')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("before: " + this.contas);
            this.contas = response.data;
            console.log("after: " + this.contas);
        });
},
```

The problem is I can't access `this.contas` from within `axios.get()`. I've tried `Vue.set(this, 'contas', response.data);` and `window.listaPagarComponent.contas = response.data;` without success.

My console shows:

```
before: undefined
after: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

But Vue Devtools shows only:

```
contas: Array[1]
  0: Object
    id: 3
    nome: "Conta de telefone"
    pago: false
    valor: 55.99
    vencimento: "22/08/2016"
```

Here's my [full code](http://pastebin.com/3Seqkk6L).

Comment: Try to use `created()` hook instead `beforeMount()`.And if you already have defined some data in contas array, then I think into promise you should do array.push.

Comment: Okay, could you please create new array in data model, and set response data to it ? And then checkout, does items are stored in array.Unfortunately I don't work with Axios, I'd rather go with Vue resource.

Comment: @Belmin Nothing changes... And it's only a debug test value. I don't want this value. The problem is I can't use `this.contas` to refer to component's data `contas`. No function works. I think axios is a "object", so when I use `this`, it refers to axios.

Comment: Yeah, already tried with a string. String `var test = ''`. Then nothing changes. I think `this` is refering to axios somehow. Vue resource doesn't work with Vue.js 2

Comment: Not sure, sorry as I said I never worked with Axios.Vue Resource works perfectly with Vue 2.I used it in many projects.Check this https://jsbin.com/jeqekexiqa/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Ok, now I've replaced `beforeMount () {}` with `mounted: function () {}` and the console shows the first log as `[__ob__: Observer]`.  Now I can push one of my objects `this.contas.push(response.data[0]);`. But I can't set my object to be **equal** my response.data with `this.contas = response.data;`. Do I need to post another question?

Comment: @Belmin has the trick, if you write `console.log(this)` inside of the promise, the result is `window`, you need store the `this` reference in a auxiliar var and use the reference var to set the values.
....
`var that = this`;

`that.contas = response.data;`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In option functions like `data` and `created`, vue binds `this` to the view-model instance for us, so we can use `this.contas`, but in the function inside `then`, `this` is not bound.

**So** you need to preserve the view-model like (`created` means the component's data structure is assembled, which is enough here, `mounted` will delay the operation more):

```
created() {
    var self = this;
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1/api/bills')
        .then(function (response) {
                self.contas = response.data;
                });
}
```

**Or** you can use arrow function in ES6 standard if you only aim to support modern browsers(or using a transpiler like babel), like:

```
created() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1/api/bills')
        .then((response) => {
                this.contas = response.data;
                });
}
```

`this` inside arrow functions are bound according to lexical context, which means the `this` in the above snippet is the same as the one in `created`, which is what we want.

Comment: Hooray! this solved my problem too... thanks. No matter how many times I learned and understand 'this' it will always create problem for me.

Comment: damn Thanks so much, just because need instance of 'this' syntax

Answer (score 24):

To be able to access this.contas inside axios.get() do you need binding "this" to keep variable usage scoped:

```
mounted() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1/api/bills')
     .then(function (response) {
        console.log("before: " + this.contas);
        this.contas = response.data;
        console.log("after: " + this.contas);
     }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: this one also true