# Set object in data from a method in VUE.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been stuck with this issues for 2 hours now and I really can't seem to get it work.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#book-search',
  data: {
    searchInput: 'a',
    books: {},
  },
  methods: {
    foo: function () {
      axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes', {
        params: {
          q: this.searchInput
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        var items = response.data.items
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

          var item = items[i].volumeInfo;

          Vue.set(this.books[i], 'title', item.title);   

        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    }
  }
});
```

When I initiate search and the API call I want the values to be passed to data so the final structure looks similar to the one below.

```
data: {
  searchInput: '',
  books: {
    "0": {
       title: "Book 1"
     },
    "1": {
       title: "Book 2"
     }
},
```

Currently I get `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: Value of `this` is different in the callback function of axios `.then()` method. You have to save the value of `this` outside before using it in callback scope.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia If I change this to `app`, that is how my Vue instance is defined, it throws a `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios can't set data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996344/axios-cant-set-data)

Comment: Notice that this is about a "traditional" JavaScript object (dictionary), not an actual `Set` object as created with `new Set()` - I came here looking how Vue handles these...

Comment: two hours for real. Sigh.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problem lies here:

```
Vue.set(this.books[i], 'title', item.title);
```

You are inside the callback context and the value of `this` is not the Vue object as you might expect it to be. One way to solve this is to save the value of `this` beforehand and use it in the callback function.

Also instead of using `Vue.set()`, try updating the books object directly.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#book-search',
  data: {
    searchInput: 'a',
    books: {},
  },
  methods: {
    foo: function () {
      var self = this;
      //--^^^^^^^^^^^^ Save this
      axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes', {
        params: {
          q: self.searchInput
          //-^^^^--- use self instead of this
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        var items = response.data.items
        var books = {};
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

          var item = items[i].volumeInfo;
          books[i] = { 'title' : item.title };
        }
        self.books = books;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    }
  }
});
```

Or if you want to use `Vue.set()` then use this:

```
Vue.set(self.books, i, {
     'title': item.title
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, this  makes a lot of sense, but I am still getting the `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error.

Comment: It helps for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

yep, the problem is about context. "this" returns not what you expect it to return.

1. you can use

   let self = this;
2. or you can use bind

   function(){this.method}.bind(this);

the second method is better.

Also google something like "how to define context in js", "bind call apply js" - it will help you to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// update component's data with some object's fields
// bad idea, use at your own risk

Object
  .keys(patch)
  .forEach(key => this.$data[key] = patch[key])
```