# Accessing VUE JS's data from Axios

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios, lexical-closures, vuetify.js

I have a Vue JS (Vuetify) App that makes an ajax request that I would like to populate a div's content with the response, however I am having difficulties accessing the instance's **data**. All examples I have seen use **this** to point to the data object, but when I do I get this error

`Unable to set property 'message' of undefined or null reference`

The app is quite simple:

**main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'


Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**App.vue**

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    ....
    message: '',
    order: {},
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    send: function() {
      axios.post(this.api+"orders",this.order).then(function(response) {
        this.message = "Your payment was successful";
        ...
      }
   }
 }
```

**this.order** is accessible without a problem with Axios' **post** method however the anonymous function that handles the promise returned seems to have a problem accessing **this.message**, in contrary to the examples I have seen.

What is it that I am doing differently here?

Comment: Your problem is this line `axios.post(this.api+"orders",this.order).then(function(response) {`. Examples may use this, but by using a second nested `function` expression, you are accessing a different dynamic this than you think you are. Pass an `=>` function to the `.then`. Basically, `.send` is the method of the vue object, but since `this` is not lexically scoped inside of `function` expressions, only inside of `=>` functions, you have the wrong `this` reference in your callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios can't set data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996344/axios-cant-set-data)

Answer (score 45):

I can think of these solutions for your problem.

1) You can create a reference to `this` and use it.

```
send: function() {
  let self = this
  axios.post(this.api + "orders", this.order).then(function(response) {
    self.message = "Your payment was successful"
  }
}
```

2) An `arrow function` will enable you to use `this` which will point to your Vue instance.

```
send: function() {
  axios.post(this.api + "orders", this.order).then(response => {
    this.message = "Your payment was successful"
  }
}
```

3) Use `bind` to assign an object to `this` which will be the current Vue instance in your case.

```
send: function() {
  axios.post(this.api + "orders", this.order).then(function(response) {
    this.message = "Your payment was successful"
  }.bind(this))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Problem solved, and recommended this answer because easy to follow

Comment: @DarkteK Cool, I'd recommend using arrow functions in this case though.

Comment: amazing answer. still saving lives in 2021

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is this line

```
axios.post(this.api+"orders",this.order).then(function(respo‌​nse) {
```

Examples may use `this` as you say however, by using a second level of nested function expression, you are accessing a different dynamic `this` than you think you are.

Basically, `send` is the method of the Vue object, but since `this` is not lexically scoped inside of `function` expressions, only inside of `=>` functions, you have the wrong `this` reference in the callback you are passing to `Promise.prototype.then`.

Here is a breakdown:

```
methods: {
  send: function() {
    // here: `this` technically refers to the `methods` object
    // but Vue lifts it to the entire view object at runtime
    axios.post(this.api + "orders", this.order)
      .then(function(response) {
        // here: `this` refers to the whatever object `the function is called on
        // if it is called as a method or bound explicitly using Function.prototype.bind
        // the Promise instance will not call it on anything
        // nor bind it to anything so `this` will be undefined
        // since you are in a module and modules are implicitly strict mode code.
        this.message = "Your payment was successful";
      });
    }
 }
```

Try this instead

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    message: "",
    order: {},
  },
  methods: {
    send: function() {
      // here: `this` technically refers to the `methods` object
      // but Vue lifts it to the entire view object at runtime
      axios.post(this.api + "orders", this.order).then(response => {
        // here: this refers to the same object as it does in `send` because
        // `=>` functions capture their outer `this` reference statically.
        this.message = "Your payment was successful";
      });
    }
  }
}
```

or better yet

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    message: "",
    order: {},
  },
  methods: {
    async send() {
      const response = await axios.post(`${this.api}orders`, this.order);
      this.message = "Your payment was successful";
    }
  }
}
```

Note in the second example, which uses JavaScript's recently standardized `async/await` functionality, we have abstracted away the need for a callback entirely so the point becomes moot.

I suggest it here, not because it relates to your question, but rather because it should be the preferred way of writing Promise driven code if you have it available which you do based on your use of other language features. It leads to clearer code when using Promises.

The key point of this answer however, is the scoping of the `this` reference.

Comment: Thanks, that helped

Comment: Aluan Haddad How would you error handle the asynch await verion?

Comment: `async`/`await` lets you use standard control structures in asynchronous code so you handle errors with `try { await f() } catch (e) {}`.