# aixos reponse data can not assign to Vue instance's data

Tags: vue.js, axios

In my vue.js project, i get an array data by axios, and want to assign to bookList variable, but failed, bookList still equal to [], could you tell me why?

```
export default {
...
data () {
  return {
    bookList: []
  }
},
mounted: function() {
  this.$nextTick(function(){
    this.viewBooks();
  });
},
methods: {
  viewBooks: function() {
    axios.get('/books.json')
      .then(res=>{
        this.bookList = res.data.bookList;
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(res.data.bookList)` return?

Comment: return correct data.

Comment: Your code works (https://jsfiddle.net/k85pnp29/1/), so there must be something wrong with some code you're not including

Answer (score 0):

The callback is on a different scope...this should work

```
methods: {
    viewBooks: function() {
        let self = this;
        axios.get('/books.json')
            .then(res=>{
                self.bookList = res.data.bookList;
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

There's also a different answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996344/axios-cant-set-data?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. I tried, and "this" binds to vue instance when i use arrow function in ES6 standard, so the problem still exists.

Comment: His callback is fine. Arrow functions capture the lexical scope.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that on the linked questions