# Async/await calls with axis and Vue.js - `.then()` callback not updating `this.something`

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm having a little trouble setting one of my `this.values` within my `Vue` application. I believe I'm either not understanding async axios calls correctly, or how async works within `axios`.

I have the following `axios` post method within my `Vue` application:

```
postRequest: async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let config = {
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": this.csrfToken,
            "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    }

    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('data', someData);

    await axios.post('{{ request_absolute_uri }}', formData, config).then(function(response) {
            this.responseMessage = response.data.message;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    console.log(this.responseMessage)
    return this.responseMessage;
}
```

My `response.data.message` is being passed back from my framework as True/true but it seems I'm not returning anything from the `postRequest` function? The post definitely hits the server as logging shows everything I want - then returns back `message = true` in json response context (using `console.log(this.responseMessage)` directly before returning the same value. However, nothing on the template changes or updates from this....

I'm assuming at this point that I have missed something incredibly simple!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios can't set data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996344/axios-cant-set-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm. I think I know what is going on here: because you're using a standard `function`, your `this` inside the `.then()` callback is not refering to the instantiated object...instead, `this.` is the calling the context of that function - with your original code, i.e., the `Promise` returned by the axios `.post` method.

Instead, I would advise using an arrow function instead so that the `this` is inherited from the outer scope, something along these lines:

```
await axios.post('{{ request_absolute_uri }}', formData, config).then( (response) => {
  this.responseMessage = response.data.message;
})
```

***N.B.*** With arrow functions, the `this.` is always inherited from the outer scope, rather than depending on the calling context of the arrow function - so you can reference `this.message` or `this.someFunction()` with ease.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm not sure exactly what is different about this answer from the code in my question...?

Comment: @GCien Hi, you're missing the arrow function `=>`, without using this your `this.` will always refer to the one returned by the `post` request and not the context provided by your `Vue` application...

Comment: Yep - I see that now, template is now updating on the new message!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "this" is out of scope inside .then statement. If you add the line:

```
var self = this;
```

at the top of your postRequest function, and then when assigning the response message use:

```
self.responseMessage = response.data.message;
```

I think that should work.