# v-for not working even when variable has object array assigned to it

Tags: php, vue.js

```
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="invoice in invoices">
                            <td>Holder</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.firstname}} {{invoice.lastname}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.telephone}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.email}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.payment_adress_1}} {{payment_country}} {{payment_postcode}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.shipping_address}} {{shipping_country}} {{shipping_postcode}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.comment}}</td>
                            <td>Holder</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.payment_method}}</td>
                            <td>Holder</td>
                            <td>Holder</td>
                            <td>Holder</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
    <script>
        const app = Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    invoices: []
                }
            },
            methods: {
                OnLoad() {
                    axios.post('invoiceConfig.php', {
                        request: 3
                    })
                    .then(function(response){
                        console.log(response.data)
                        this.invoices = response.data
                        console.log(this.invoices)
                    })
                    .catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
            },
            beforeMount(){
                this.OnLoad()
            }
        })
        const vm = app.mount('#app');
```

[image]

[image]

invoiceConfig.php is used to extract data from a database, for some reason, when console logging the response, an object array is seen, but when trying to v-for to add rows to table corresponding to the amount of objects in the list, it simply doesnt work. Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Vue.set could help you [Vuejs and Vue.set(), update array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807888/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I don't know how this works but, changing .then(function(response)... to .then(response)=>... in the OnLoad() method fixed it. I guess this is not recognized in an inner function? I followed this guide to solve it: [Axios can't set data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996344/axios-cant-set-data/72168705#72168705), first answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try the same using `computed`

```
 <tbody>
   <tr v-for="(invoice, index) in getInvoices" :key="index"> <!-- Change added in this line -->
                            <td>Holder</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.firstname}} {{invoice.lastname}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.telephone}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.email}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.payment_adress_1}} {{payment_country}} {{payment_postcode}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.shipping_address}} {{shipping_country}} {{shipping_postcode}}</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.comment}}</td>
                            <td>Holder</td>
                            <td>{{invoice.payment_method}}</td>
                            <td>Holder</td>
                            <td>Holder</td>
                            <td>Holder</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<script>
        const app = Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    invoices: []
                }
            },
            // change added below
            computed: {
             getInvoices() {
               return this.invoices.length ? this.invoices : [];
             }
            },
            methods: {
                OnLoad() {
                    axios.post('invoiceConfig.php', {
                        request: 3
                    })
                    .then(function(response){
                        console.log(response.data)
                        this.invoices = response.data
                        console.log(this.invoices)
                    })
                    .catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
            },
            created(){ // change added
                this.OnLoad();
            }
        })
        const vm = app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, unfortunately, this does not work, I'm really pulling out my hair right now!!! HAHAHA, everything seems correct to me!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your code should work, I just created a below code snippet by adding some time out to see if `beforeMount()` is binding the data in the DOM after some interval or not but it is working.

Are you getting any error in console ? Can you please try with some dummy/mock response to debug the actual root cause.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    invoices: []
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.OnLoad();
  },
  methods: {
    OnLoad() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.invoices = [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Invoice 1'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Invoice 2'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Invoice 3'
        }]
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="invoice in invoices" :key="invoice.id">
      <td>{{ invoice.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ invoice.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```